# Apply function on a particular column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

```
def include_mean():
    if pd.isnull('Age'):
        if 'Pclass'==1:
            return 38
        elif 'Pclass'==2:
            return 30
        elif 'Pclass'==3:
            return 25
        else: return 'Age'

train['Age']=train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(include_mean(),axis=1)
```

why is the above code giving me a type error.

```
 TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I now know the right code which is

```
def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
if Pclass == 1:
            return 37
elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29
else:
            return 24
else:
        return Age

train['Age'] = train[['Age','Pclass']].apply(impute_age,axis=1)
```

Now I want to know why are the changes required i.e. the exact reasons behind them. What is 'cols' doing here.

Comment: Can you fix some of the indentation in your examples? It's a bit unclear where the else statements come in. Also the logic in the top and bottom cases seem totally different? (top has a Pclass=-3, while bottom does not)

Comment: Regardless, I think you may want to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column?noredirect=1&lq=1. `numpy.select` is likely the best way to create your new column when you need to implement `elif` logic.

Answer (score 1):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

When you're using the `apply` method on a panda dataframe, the function you pass to apply is called on every column(or row, depending on the `axis` parameter which defaults to `0`, the column axis). 
So your function must have a parameter for the row which `apply` will pass to it.

```
def include_mean():
    if pd.isnull('Age'):
        if 'Pclass'==1:
            return 38
        elif 'Pclass'==2:
            return 30
        elif 'Pclass'==3:
            return 25
        else: return 'Age'
```

There are a few issues with this.

1. `'Pclass'==1:` is guaranteed to be `False`, since you're comparing a string(`'Pclass'`) and an integer(`1`), which cannot be equal. What you want is to compare the value of the `Pclass` entry of a column, which you can retrieve by indexing the column: `col["Pclass"]`, or `col[1]` if `Pclass` is the second column.
2. if `pd.isnull('Age')` is `False`, the function returns `None`. Since the string `'Age'` is not null, this should always be the case. When you do `d.apply(include_mean())`, you're calling `include_mean`, which returns `None`, and then pass that value to `apply`. But `apply` expects a callable(e.g. a function).
3. In the `else` clause, you're returning the string `'Age'`. This means your dataframe would have had the value `'Age'` in some cells.

Your second sample fixes those issues: the impute_age function now takes a parameters for the row(`cols`), the value of the `Age` and `Pclass` columns are looked up and compared, and you pass that function without calling it to the `apply` method.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python.  To answer your question, especially at the beginning phase, sometimes you just need to crack open a fresh IPython notebook and try stuff out:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: def function(x):
   ...:     return x+1
   ...:
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'values':range(10)})
   ...: print(df)
   ...:
   values
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
8       8
9       9

In [2]: print(df.apply(function))
   values
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
```

In your question, `cols` is the value for each row you're looping over.

Comment: still did not get it, while calling the function the code is not passing on the values for the 'cols' list. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @SauravJaswal Nope.  I'll take down the answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Do not use `apply(axis=1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4333359). Instead, you should set the values on a subset using `.loc`. This is a simple mapping for the top case.

```
m = train.Age.isnull()
d = {1: 38, 2: 30, 3: 25}

train.loc[m, 'Age'] = train.loc[m, 'Pclass'].map(d)
```

---

For the bottom case because of the `else` clause we can use `np.select`. The way this works is we create a condition list that follows the order of the if, elif else logic. Then we supply a choice list to select from when we encounter the first `True`. Since you have nested logic we need to first unnest it so that it logically reads as

```
if age is null and pclass == 1
elif age is null and pclass == 2
elif age is null 
else
```

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [50, 60, 70, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'Pclass': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, np.NaN, 1]})
#    Age  Pclass
#0  50.0     1.0
#1  60.0     1.0
#2  70.0     1.0
#3   NaN     1.0
#4   NaN     2.0
#5   NaN     NaN
#6   NaN     1.0

m = df.Age.isnull()
conds = [m & df.Pclass.eq(1),
         m & df.Pclass.eq(2),
         m]
choices = [37, 29, 24]

df['Age'] = np.select(conds, choices, default=df.Age)
                                      # |
                                      # Takes care of else, i.e. Age not null
print(df)
#    Age  Pclass
#0  50.0     1.0
#1  60.0     1.0
#2  70.0     1.0
#3  37.0     1.0
#4  29.0     2.0
#5  24.0     NaN
#6  37.0     1.0
```

Comment: Completely good-willed question, no malice intended, I promise: did you realize you were being the caricature of a bad SO answerer when you posted this?  OP is clearly curious about learning how `apply` gets an argument passed, and your answer is to not use `apply` in this case, but `loc`.  Again, not trying to be rude, I just wanted to know if you were aware or if you are so tunnel-visioned you can't see how answering something other than how `apply`'s argument works can only frustrate a beginner.

Comment: @user1717828 The issue is that this is the XY problem. The user needs to map null values of age based on `Pclass`. They believe that this should be done with `apply`, iterating over the rows, so they ask a question about why apply does't work. The problem is that there's no sense in dealing with that problem because `apply` is 100% not the way to answer this problem. It's horribly inefficient and just should not be used. There's a reason this answer has 144 upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4333359

Comment: @user1717828 so yes, perhaps my answer was a bit blunt, but honestly I'd rather focus my time showing users the proper way to solve their problem with the correct tools, instead of trying to debug a tool they shouldn't be using in the first place. But your point is taken, I will add a section illustrating "how" one could make it work with `apply`, and why it's not useful.